# Unable to access my one specific C# script in Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am a newbie at unity, and I keep getting this error when I try to access my script. It runs fine when I am trying to access some other script, but it gets error when I try to access `GetAqiInfo`
script specifically! Thanks a ton in advanced.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of code .. copy&paste it as **text** and format it using the `{ }` button

Comment: I'm so sorry, I would keep this in mind.

Comment: also what does your question have to do with `java`, `android` or `json` ?

Comment: I really forgot to realise that the snippet I have pasted has nothing to do with Java, Android and JSON although the whole application is android and uses all three of those technologies. This was my first question on this platform, I'll keep these intricate details in mind the next time. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a namespace in your c# classes, then you just add it as using statement at the top of the class

In your class AquiInfo.cs do something like this

```
namespace SomeNamespace{
    public class AquiInfo... {
     ...
    }
}
```

You probably also want to set a namespace but just for this to work you will need to add at the top

```
using SomeNamespace;
```

After this the error should go away.

Comment: Hey Anathorn, thank you for your reply. I realized all it was was me not naming the file name and the class name same (duh!). As soon as I did that, no more errors!